# Chrome: XMLHttpRequest cannot load, cross-origin request error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome, xmlhttprequest

I know this is a bug in Chrome, and that this works in every other browser.

Here is the simple code throwing the error:

```
$(function() {
    $('#content').load('home.html' + '#container').hide().fadeIn('slow');
});
```

My question is, is this only a local host error, will the still happen in chrome if the website is on a server?

Comment: Where are you on with this? A `file://` URL, `http://localhost`, or something else?

Comment: tried both, apache and local files

Comment: That seems strange - but it definitely shouldn't happen on a normal http server. The rules around how browsers handle filesystem and local requests can be weird and arcane, but they shouldn't carry into the web (unless something else is wrong.) Can you quote the full error message you're getting please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that it is only for localhost in server works fine.

Try this extension of crhome: [Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: *](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi)

Comment: Yeah, you're right, just put it on a server and it works across the board thanks